# Submenu not showing in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drop-down-menu, drupal-7

I have a `Drupal 7` site. I need to create menu & submenu.

I am using Drupal `Mega Menu`module for this.

Issue:
**Submenu not showing up on hover on menu item**

This is my menu structure:

[image: My Menu Structure]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **jquery version** with **jquery update module**.. try different combinations.. it should work..

*Use jQuery is recommended by Mega Menu*